# TableView does not update in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk

I have problem reloadData. If I put `[tableView reloadData];` under didSelectRowAtIndexPath it refreshes any time I did select row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {
    [tableView reloadData];
    DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = nil;
    [detailsViewController setMainImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
```

But I need to refresh while is loading. So I put under

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

but I'm getting error message "Unknown receiver 'tableView'..."

I also try with [self.tableView reloadData]; but error message "Property 'tableView' not found on object 'FavoritesTabViewController".

Comment: why do you need to reload the whole data after selecting a row? what exactly do you want to do in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: When is your tableView created? Does FavoritesTabViewController inherit from `UITableviewController`? Do you inherit from UIViewController and then create the tableView?

Comment: I'm trying to reloadData, I'm getting error message so I just put under didSelectRowAtIndexPath jus to see if will reloadData. And it did so it is working there but not under viewWillAppear. Why is working under didSelectRowAtIndexPath but not under viewWillAppear and how to fix it?

Comment: Yes GianPac I did inherit from UIViewController

Comment: If you could also show the code where you create the tableView. Put a breakpoint on [tableView reloadData] and check if tableView is not nil.

Comment: I'm using contentView instead of tableView duh..so after I put [contentView reloadData]; it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that tableView is not in scope in the ViewWillAppear method. 
In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath it is in scope as it is passed to this method.

Answer (score 0):

try reloading the table view in cellForRowAtIndexPath becoz that is call everytime the table is loaded